# How to Persist YouTube Data API V3 Authentication with google-api-python-client for Personal Usage?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am working on a project to programmatically upload videos to YouTube using the YouTube Data API v3 and google-api-python-client. The code is for personal use only.

Here's how I am currently handling authentication:

```
# imports
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
    'client_secrets.json',
    scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload']
)

credentials = flow.run_local_server(port=8080)

youtube = build("youtube", "v3", credentials=credentials)
# code to upload the video
```

The code works as expected, but the issue I am facing is that every time I run the script, it opens a browser window where I have to sign in to authenticate. This is not very convenient for me as I would like this to be an automated process.

Initially, I tried using an API key for authentication, but received a 401 error with the message:

```
API keys are not supported by this API. Expected OAuth2 access token or other authentication credentials that assert a principal. See Cloud Docs on Authentication
```

I have reviewed the documentation, but I am a bit confused about which authentication method would suit my needs without going through the full publishing process.

Could anyone guide me on how to persist authentication so that I don't have to manually sign in every time the script runs? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: fix your code so that you store the refresh token and use it when you need to run it again.

Comment: Could you answer the question with an example or a link to an example? I'll validate your answer. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my video insert sample see if it doesnt help the refresh token is stored in token.json

```
#   To install the Google client library for Python, run the following command:
#   pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client google-auth-httplib2 google-auth-oauthlib

from __future__ import print_function

import os.path

import google.auth.exceptions
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube']

def main():

    """Shows basic usage of the YouTube v3 API.
    Uploads a private video to YouTube
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        try:
            creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
            creds.refresh(Request())
        except google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError as error:
            # if refresh token fails, reset creds to none.
            #creds = None
            print(f'An error occurred: {error}')
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'C:\YouTube\dev\credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())

    try:
        service = build('youtube', 'v3', credentials=creds)

        body = dict(
            snippet=dict(
                title="Test",
                description="test",
                tags="tes"
            ),
            status=dict(
                privacyStatus="private"
            )
        )

        media = MediaFileUpload("dummyvideo.mkv", chunksize=-1, resumable=True)

        results = service.videos().insert(
                part=",".join(body.keys()),
                body=body,
                media_body=media).execute()
        print(F'video ID: {results.get("id")}')

    except HttpError as error:
        # TODO(developer) - Handle errors from drive API.
        print(f'An error occurred: {error}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```